# Geometrical significance of $f(x, y, z)$

Tags: graphing-functions

Keeping it brief and simple,  $f(x) = y$ can be plotted in $xy$-plane. $f(x, y) = z$ can be plotted in 3D coordinate system. But what happens as we come across a function like this one $f(x, y, z) = w$. Can we plot it? In what system?

I have a picture of a book's page to explain my problem lucidly but it aint allowing me to put an image.

Comment: Works in standard four-dimensional space ...

Comment: Four dimensions? Are you kidding me, @HagenVonEitzen

Comment: No he isn't kidding, it generalizes naturally to functions like $w = f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)$ which exists in $(n+1)D$ space

Comment: @triatticus how can one possibly imagine more than 3 dimensions?

Comment: You don't, humans cannot imagine more than we live in, but they are of great theoretical and physical importance. A Hilbert space for example is an infinite dimensional function space used in quantum mechanics

Comment: @user529760 sometimes without latex is better. I see you edited the title and typed f(xyz) latex there but imagine how many would find this post on google due to the keyword f(xyz) if this wasn't in Latex.

Comment: OK. I will keep that in mind. This post seems not influenced by that effect since I typed "math stackexchange graphing f(xyz)" in Google and I found this post in the first place.

Comment: What's the point if you had to type 'math stackexchange' ? Of course this keyword will directly take you to the posts on math.SE. Not everyone knows about math.SE so not everyone is going to type that out. Anyways I appreciate your help but be careful next time and have a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a map $f:\>A\to B$ then the *graph* $${\cal G}(f):=\bigl\{(x,y)\in A\times B\bigm| y=f(x)\bigr\}$$ is a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$. It follows that the graph ${\cal G}(f)$ of a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ is a subset of ${\mathbb R}^3\times{\mathbb R}={\mathbb R}^4$.

For ordinary humans it is impossible to visualize such a graph, which is a three-dimensional hypersurface in ${\mathbb R}^4$. But there are other means to obtain a "graphical" representation of such an $f$, e.g., the following: Imagine that $f(x,y,z)$ is the temperature in ${}^\circ$C at the point $(x,y,z)$. Then one could draw the isothermal surfaces of $f$. These surfaces *foliate* three-space as do the pages of a book, or the skins of an onion.

Comment: Wow :::::::::::